# Converting a pointer to a numeric value for hashing - should I use `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t`?

Tags: c, pointers, hash

I need to convert an arbitrary pointer to a numeric value in order to pass it through a hash function.

Ideally, just for kicks, I would also like the number to be convertible back to the same pointer. But that's not a must.

After looking through SO and the interweb, I'm not clear on whether `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t` is the right tool for the job. Most places mention `uintptr_t`, but some place said I may lose some of the bits of the original pointer by using the unsigned type.

Clarifications would be welcome.

Comment: I think the assumption C makes is that a pointer already *is* a number (the address in memory of the thing it points to), so it doesn't really need to be "converted".  What are you trying to accomplish by hashing these?

Comment: @ScottHunter I need to use them as keys in a hash table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I need to convert an arbitrary pointer to a numeric value in order to pass it through a hash function.*

Both do, `intptr_t` as well as `uintptr_t`.

> *I would also like the number to be convertible back to the same pointer.*

Converting back the integer to a pointer value is also possible and [backed by the C-Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.4).

Comment: Is it possible that two different void* pointers would be converted to the same `uintptr_t` value?

Comment: @AvivCohn: The fact that conversion from integer back to the original pointer value is possible implicitly answers your question with "no".

Comment: For completeness: Conversion is only specified (and with this required to be defined) for: pointer-value --> integer --> pointer-value. It is **not** specified for integer --> pointer-value --> integer!